# Flip UIView without dim effect

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics, core-animation

I am trying to create a flip animation in one of my views. I managed to get the animation working but it looks horrible because the card (which has a white background color) dims its color to be darker during the animation.

Do you know if there is a way to get rid of this dim effect to maintain the original color of the cards during the whole animation?

[image]

For further reference, please find below a simple view controller reproducing my problem.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var cardView: UIView = {
        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
        return backgroundView
    }()
    
    private lazy var flipButton: UIButton = {
        let flipButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
        flipButton.setTitle("Flip", for: .normal)
        flipButton.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        flipButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(flipCard), for: .touchUpInside)
        return flipButton
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        view.addSubview(cardView)
        cardView.addSubview(flipButton)
        
        cardView.center = view.center
    }
    
    @objc
    func flipCard() {
        UIView.transition(with: cardView, duration: 10, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

u can use

```
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 6, delay: 0, options: []) {
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                    self.cardView.transform3D = CATransform3DRotate(self.cardView.layer.transform, CGFloat.pi, 0, 1, 0)
                }
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 1) {
                    self.cardView.transform3D = CATransform3DRotate(self.cardView.layer.transform, CGFloat.pi, 0, 1, 0)
                }
            }
```

instead of

```
UIView.transition(with: cardView, duration: 10, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: nil, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through UIView.animate() also in Swift 5,

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration/2, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear) {
    targetView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: .pi )
} completion: { (_) in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration/2, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear) {
         targetView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: .pi * 2)
    } 
}
```